# why i couldn't see any text in "http://crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=http://mydomain.com#!article"?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwtp

Ok, i found this link https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/CrawlerSupport#Using_gwtp-crawler-service that explain how you can make your GWTP app crawlable.

I got some GWTP experience, but i know nothing about AppEngine.

Google said its "crawlservice.appspot.com" can parse any Ajax page. Now I have a page "http://mydomain.com#!article" that has an artice that was pulled from Database. Say that page has the text "**this is my article**". Now I open this link:

crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=http://mydomain.com#!article, then i can see all javascript but I couldn't find the text "**this is my article**".

Why?

Now let check with a real life example

open this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/Syi04ArKl4k & you will see the text "**If i open that url in IE**"

Now you open http://crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/Syi04ArKl4k you can see all javascript but there is no text "**If i open that url in IE**",

Why is it?

SO if i use `http://crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=mydomain#!article` then Can google crawler be able to see the text in `mydomain#!article`?

also why the `key=123456`, it means everyone can use this service?   do we have our own key? does google limit the number of calls to their service?

Could you explain all these things?

**Extra Info:**

Christopher suggested me to use this example 
https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/tree/master/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-crawler-service

However, I ran into other problem. My app is a pure GWTP, it doesn't have appengine-web.xml in WEB-INF. I have no idea what is `appengine` or `GAE` mean or what is `Maven`.

DO i need to register AppEngine?

My Appp may have a lot of traffic. Also I am using Godaddy VPS. I don't want to register App Engine since I have to pay for Google for extra traffic.

Everything in my GWTP App is ok right now except Crawler Function.

So if I don't use Google App Engine, then how can i build Crawler Function for GWTP?

I tried to use HTMLUnit for my app, but HTMLUnit doesn't work for GWTP (See details in here [Why HTMLUnit always shows the HostPage no matter what url I type in (Crawlable GWT APP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697516/why-htmlunit-always-shows-the-hostpage-no-matter-what-url-i-type-in-crawlable-g) )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to approach Google groups discussions crawler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211887/how-to-approach-google-groups-discussions-crawler)

Comment: @Howlin, this is Crawlable solution for GWTP, not for Python, this is a very valuable question, please do not close it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are [not allowed to crawl Google Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211887/how-to-approach-google-groups-discussions-crawler). Probably they are actively trying to prevent this, so you do not see the expected content.

Comment: so what about my own domain, i didn't see any text in http://crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=mydomain#!article & i did not set anything in my website

Comment: I can't test it as you did not provide url to your app. Also you are asking why a particular tool (crawlservice) isn't working: this is not a programming question, nor is it related to AppEngine or Gwt.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple points I wish to elaborate on:

1. The Google Code documentation is no longer maintained. You should look on Github instead: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Crawler-Support
2. You shouldn't use http://crawlservice.appspot.com. This isn't a Google service, it's out of date and we may decide to delete it down the road. This only serves as a public example. You should create your own application on App Engine (https://appengine.google.com/)
3. There is a sample here (https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/tree/master/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-crawler-service) using GWTP's Crawler Service. You can basically copy-paste it. Just make sure you update the `<application>` tag in *appengine-web.xml* to the name of your application and use your own service key in *CrawlerModule*.

Finally, if your client uses GWTP and you followed the documentation, it will work. If you want to try it manually, you must encode the Query Parameters.
For example `http://crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=http://www.arcbees.com#!service` will not work because the hash (everything including and after #) is not sent to the server.
On the other hand `http://crawlservice.appspot.com/?key=123456&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arcbees.com%2F%23!service` will work.

Comment: Hi Christopher, I asked so many question about Crawlable GWTp in many days before, but no one could explain me clearly what is going on. Your answer is like a light at the end of the tunnel. It's a very valuable piece of info. However, I got another problem. I updated my question, so please read my question at the end form "Extra info".